# empty string from special folder (loadUserProfile is "true")

Tags: c#, iis-7, directory, special-folders

I need to use some folder for temp files. 
I tried to use

```
    string directoryPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/tempFiles");
```

but when I publish it to IIS I had permission issues.

So I tried to use :

```
    string directoryPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

It works fine when I run my web application from VS2012, but I get an empty string when I publish it to iis and run it there.

**I checked and  loadUserProfile is "true"**.

Any other suggestion?

Comment: Is you IIS running in a full trust Environment?

Comment: @TamarG: Try setting the ApplicationPoolIdentity to LocalSystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the special paths are specific to the logged-in user, and special user accounts such as apppool may have no such folder. I'd suggest either using GetTempPath ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx ) or creating a directory inside your website for such a purpose (but with security set so that website users can't browse to it).